# Subqueries in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, subquery

I am taking a SQL course and am completely stumped on this question.

Using a subquery have a query that returns:
CustomerID, EmailAddress, FirstName, LastName, '#3: Customers who have ordered than 1 product' as
queryInfo
The subquery from this query will be: All customers with who have ordered more than 1 product

Note: More than one Product, not Quantity > 1 So a customer who ordered 10 of the same
product is NOT what I'm looking for.

Here is the full query I used:

```sql
SELECT c.CustomerID
     , c.EmailAddress
     , c.FirstName
     , c.LastName
     , '#3: Customers who have ordered more than 1 product' AS queryInfo
  FROM Customers c
 WHERE c.CustomerID IN (
           SELECT p.ProductID 
             FROM Customers c 
             JOIN Orders o
                  ON c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
             JOIN OrderItems oi
                  ON o.OrderID = oi.OrderID
             JOIN Products p
                  ON oi.ProductID = p.ProductID 
         GROUP BY p.ProductID 
           HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
         )
     ;
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong, but any input is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: [Edit] the question and provide a [example], i.e. the `CREATE` statements of the tables or other objects involved (paste the **text**, don't use images, don't link to external sites), `INSERT` statements for sample data (dito) and the desired result with that sample data in tabular text format.

Comment: why has the customer id the same id as the product?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has a number of issues:

- You can simplify to a  `COUNT(DISTINCT` here as you want the number of distinct products
- The subquery returns `ProductID` you would need `CustomerID` instead. Since you need the grouped count, you are better off with an `EXISTS` query instead
- You are querying `Customer` again unnecessarily. `Products` is also not needed as you can get `ProductID` from `OrderItems`

```sql
SELECT c.CustomerID
     , c.EmailAddress
     , c.FirstName
     , c.LastName
     , '#3: Customers who have ordered more than 1 product' AS queryInfo
  FROM Customers c
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
             FROM Orders o
             JOIN OrderItems oi
                  ON o.OrderID = oi.OrderID
             WHERE c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
           HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT oi.ProductID) > 1
         )
     ;
```

You could also remove the `HAVING` and check the `COUNT(DISTINCT` from the subquery on the outside:

```sql
 WHERE (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT oi.ProductID)
             FROM Orders o
             JOIN OrderItems oi
                  ON o.OrderID = oi.OrderID
             WHERE c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
         ) > 1
```

Comment: Nice (+1) - don't have a running instance of SQL Server - would there be any difference in the efficiency of the two queries or does the optimiser fold them into one?

Comment: I think it would be exactly the same, but you can check the query plans to verify.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong? From your point of view?
But:

1. the subselect returns productid instead of customerid which means the data returned is wrong
2. the customer table and product table in subselect is bot needed. You can group by productid in orderitems table and return customerid from orderheader

Comment: I finally have it figured it out. I just needed the HAVING COUNT to actually count the ProductID instead of just using an *. Thanks so much for the input!

Comment: Kindly mark the answer as helpful and/or correct if you found it so!